# Hide button "Edit list" on other user profile page for moderators

Tags: feature-request, bug, profile-page, moderator-tools

For example, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2/stanislav?tab=profile.

> [image]

Moderators can see link "Edit list", which opens https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/hidecommunities/2 page. But we can't edit this list.

So, I guess, better to hide this link for moderators.